# How to show specific column in mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I tried to show particular columns in mongodb colletion.but its not working.how to show particular columnns.

**user_collection**

```
[{
"user_name":"hari",  
"user_password":"123456"
}]
```

**find_query**

```
db.use_collection.find({},{projection:{user_name:1}})
```

**I got output**

```
[{
"user_name":"hari",  
"user_password":"123456"
}]
```

**Excepted output**

```
[{
"user_name":"hari",  
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
db.use_collection.find({}, {user_name:1, _id: 0 })
```

In that way you get the field `user_name` and exclude the `_id`.

Extra info:
[project fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only) and [project fields excluding the id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-fields)

With aggregate:

```
db.use_collection.aggregate( [ { $project : { _id: 0, user_name : 1 } } ] )
```

Comment: I tried it but its showing whole record @Alejandro Montilla

Comment: That is strange, can you use `aggregate`??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.use_collection.find({}, {user_password:0, _id: 0 ,user_name:1  })
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Mongo query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$project":
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "first_name": 1,
        }
    }
])
```

Or in ruby (Mongoid)

```
User.collection.aggregate(
  [
    "$project":
    {
        "_id": 0,
        "first_name": 1,
    }
  ]
)
```

If you try to inspect the record, you can convert it into an array first (e.g. `User.collection.aggregate(...).to_a`)

You can use the official mongodb [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) when writing in Mongoid, usually  you just need to use double quote on the property name on the left hand side, to make it work on Mongoid.